# Cannot style Jquery element using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Jquery selectmenu called #Main which implicitly gets a #Main-button. When I try to set #Main-button's width using css as

```
#Main-button {
 width:200px;
}
```

it has no effect. 
When I explicitly set

```
$( "#Main" ).selectmenu({ width:200})
```

it has the desired effect and under Firebug I see that it has appended a style="width:200" on the #Main-button, which is what I tried using CSS at the first place.

What is different? I've checked that the my CSS style sheet gets called AFTER the Jquery one, so there is no precedence issue

Also I notice that html elements turned to Jquery elements cannot be styled using CSS targeted at the specific element, even with the use of unique id's,but require the use of Jquery classes like .ui-menu etc
why do they behave differently? are there any specific styling gudilines when Jquery is involved?

Comment: `#Main-button` != `#Main`

Comment: you should use `$( "#Main-button" ).selectmenu({ width:200})`

Comment: Your elements are different !!

Comment: Just for reference OP is using http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Comment: In the api reference they used `select{width: 200px}` to set the width. Can you use `select#Main{width: 200px;}`?

Comment: Also the order of css and javascript changing css properties is not relevant. js will almost always overide css.

Comment: Tag the question correctly so nobody will get it as unclear. I wasn't the only one misguided by your lack of information - review the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you've

```
#Main-button {
   width:200px;
}
```

but the JS is adding dynamic inline style based on content. So it's having `style` attribute.

So in terms of CSS specificity their CSS beats you.

You must use `!important` in your rule to avoid overriding of your CSS.

```
#Main-button {
   width:200px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To style selectmenu or every jquery widget, you need to use jquery default classes. Your selector must be like

**#Main-button.ui-selectmenu-menu li a**

And also you can extend ***_renderItem and _renderMenu*** functions of selectmenu for different styling.